# How to subscribe to public YUM repository in Oracle Linux

Tags: linux, virtualbox, yum, oracle-linux

I would like to subscribe to the following Oracle yum repository so I can install virtual box guest additions packages.

https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/developer/x86_64/index.html

Where can I find the .repo file URL in order for me to add this to my Oracle Linux subscription list?

Edit: I am already subscribed to the Oracle public yum repo

```
[root@localhost yum.repos.d]# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: langpacks, ulninfo
repo id               repo name                 status
ol6_UEK_latest/x86_64 Latest Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel for Oracle Lin   820
ol6_latest/x86_64     Oracle Linux 7Server Latest (x86_64)                 11,323
ol7_UEKR5/x86_64      Latest Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel Release 5 for     108
ol7_latest/x86_64     Oracle Linux 7Server Latest (x86_64)                11,688
repolist: 23,939


[root@localhost yum.repos.d]# yum search vbox
Loaded plugins: langpacks, ulninfo
============================== N/S matched: vbox ===============================
isdn4k-utils-vboxgetty.x86_64 : ISDN voice box (getty)

Name and summary matches only, use "search all" for everything.
```

Answer (score 0):

On the same web server there is a [page](https://yum.oracle.com/getting-started.html) which describe very well the process.

> To configure CentOS, Red Hat Enterprise Linux or Scientific Linux with
>   Oracle Linux yum server:
>
> To convert your system to Oracle Linux, see these instructions for switching from CentOS. To install individual packages from Oracle
>   Linux yum server, begin by importing the Oracle Linux GPG key based on
>   these instructions. Then, download and copy the appropriate yum
>   configuration file in place, by running the following commands as
>   root:
>
> ```
> Oracle Linux 7
>
> # cd /etc/yum.repos.d
> # wget https://yum.oracle.com/public-yum-ol7.repo
> Oracle Linux 7 for ARM (aarch64)
>
> # cd /etc/yum.repos.d
> # wget https://yum.oracle.com/aarch64/public-yum-ol7.repo
> Oracle Linux 6
>
> # cd /etc/yum.repos.d
> # wget https://yum.oracle.com/public-yum-ol6.repo
> Oracle Linux 5
>
> # cd /etc/yum.repos.d
> # wget https://yum.oracle.com/public-yum-el5.repo
> Oracle Linux 4, Update 6 or Newer
> # cd /etc/yum.repos.d
> # mv Oracle-Base.repo Oracle-Base.repo.disabled
> # wget https://yum.oracle.com/public-yum-el4.repo
> ```
>
> By default, the latest repository is enabled. If you want to change the default, you can enable an alternative repository by
>   editing the yum configuration file.
>           Open the yum configuration file in a text editor
>           Locate the section in the file for the repository want to enable, e.g. [public_ol6_addons]
>           Change enabled=0 to enabled=1

Comment: I already appear to be subscribed to that repo. See edit in original post.

Comment: @jthomp, yes, you are already subscribed. If you have other problem please create new question for it.

Comment: I am already subscribed to the oracle public repo, but this is not the repo that I am looking to subscribe to. I am looking to subscribe to the ol7 developer repo. Anyway, I fixed the problem by manually adding the entry into the yum.conf file.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding the entry manually into the yum.conf file.

[This](https://blogs.oracle.com/scoter/vbox-ga-rpms) Oracle blog helped